# How to only render cards as per the availability of data?

Tags: reactjs

```
  const [currentIndexes, setCurrentIndexes] = useState([1,2,3,4]);
  let displayCreditorsData = currentIndexes.map((e) => allCreditorsData[e]);
  const totalCreditors = allCreditorsData.length;

  function nextCards() {
    let indexes=[];
    currentIndexes.map((position, index) => {
      if (position === allCreditorsData.length) {
        return indexes.push((position = 0));
      } else {
        return indexes.push(position + 1);
      }
    });
    setCurrentIndexes(indexes);
    displayCreditorsData = (indexes.map((e) => allCreditorsData[e]));
  }

  function prevCards() {
    let indexes = [];
    currentIndexes.map((position, index) => {
      if (position === 0) {
        return indexes.push((position = totalCreditors - 1));
      } else {
        return indexes.push(position - 1);
      }
    });
    setCurrentIndexes(indexes);
    displayCreditorsData = (indexes.map((e) => allCreditorsData[e]));  
  }
```

I have the above code which lets me render some data in cards. If I have 4 or more than 4 data, I dont have any issue. But when I have less than 4, I get the extra card which is just the template of the card design. I tried to limit currentIndexes state to [1], but that than only displays 1 card in the space which can accomodate 4 in total.

I checked other solutions but they were about just rendering the data in cards, and couldn't address my problem properly. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Do you want to show displayCreditordData on the last render? it's counter-intuitive. I have added the solution, if it isn't the case, let me know.

Comment: I have space to display 4 cards. So when I have more than 4 data row, its all fine. My problem is when I have less than 4 data row. Having less than 4 data row will cause the missing data cards to be rendered with the default template of the card. My problem is if I have only 1 data row, other three cards appears as well with just headings and null values for them like:    CN: {prop.cn}, here cn is empty. So i dont want other cards to display when there is less than 4 cards. But when there are 4 or more cards my code shows 4 cards and then circles around the data rows pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

When allCreditorsData array size is less than 4, else block of `nextCards` and `prevCards` leads to pushing unwanted index to indexes variable and further goes to dispalyCreditorsData.

## Solution

Used two useEffect.

First useEffect -> To fetch the data and to set the currentIndexes when YourComponent renders for the first time

Second useEffect -> To set display data when any of the variables change from `[allCreditorsData, currentIndexes]`

Added 1000ms delay to mimic asynchronous operation.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [allCreditorsData, setAllCreditorsData] = useState([]);
  const [displayCreditorsData, setDisplayCreditorsData] = useState([]);
  const [currentIndexes, setCurrentIndexes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const hardcodedResponseData = [
          "Creditor 1",
          "Creditor 2",
          "Creditor 3",
        ];
        setAllCreditorsData(hardcodedResponseData);
        setCurrentIndexes(
          Array.from(
            { length: Math.min(4, hardcodedResponseData.length) },
            (_, i) => i
          )
        );
      }, 1000);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (allCreditorsData.length > 0) {
      setDisplayCreditorsData(
        currentIndexes.map((index) => allCreditorsData[index])
      );
    }
  }, [allCreditorsData, currentIndexes]);

  const nextCards = () => {
    const totalCreditors = allCreditorsData.length;
    setCurrentIndexes((prevIndexes) =>
      prevIndexes.map((index) => (index + 1) % totalCreditors)
    );
  };

  const prevCards = () => {
    const totalCreditors = allCreditorsData.length;
    setCurrentIndexes((prevIndexes) =>
      prevIndexes.map((index) => (index - 1 + totalCreditors) % totalCreditors)
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {displayCreditorsData.map((creditor, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <p>{creditor}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
      {displayCreditorsData && displayCreditorsData.length > 0 && (
        <>
          {" "}
          <button onClick={prevCards}>Previous</button>
          <button onClick={nextCards}>Next</button>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```

## Logic of event handler

In nextCards function`(index + 1) % totalCreditors. It increments the index by 1 and then takes the modulo wrt totalCreditors. If the index reaches the end of the array, the modulo will return 0. Similarly, you can think for prevCards function

If you wanna play around with [code](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/thirsty-fire-rp6ds8?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A1%2C1-73%2C1).

Comment: how many cards will be rendered at a time with this approach?

Comment: @BibekBhattarai I have explained my solution, do checkout

Comment: ok i got the logic. the array.from line will return sth like [0] for 1 data row or [0,1,2] for 3  data row, [0,1,2,3] if 4 or more of data row are present as 4 will be min number in that case. i console logged the array.from line and indeed i am getting [0,1]. but for some reason 'const displayCreditorsData = currentIndexes.map((index) => allCreditorsData[index]);' this line is not working as intented, the data row are not being mapped into dispalycreditorsdata, and so i am getting no cards at all. also i noticed u passed allcreditorsdata as prop, but i am getting them through an api call.

Comment: @BibekBhattarai Could you please share code of how you are getting allCreditorsData?

Comment: //fetch all creditors list start
  useEffect(() => {
    const allCreditors = () => {
      fetchAllCreditors()
      ?.then((response)=>{
        setAllCreditorsData(response?.data);
        setLoading(true);
      }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error);
      })
    };
    allCreditors();
  }, []);
  //fetch all creditors list end

Comment: @BibekBhattarai I have updated the solution, please do checkout

Comment: setDisplayCreditorsData(
        currentIndexes.map((index) => allCreditorsData[index])
      );
This part doesn't work. displayCreditorsData remains empty. And assuming value might be there but it needs to get a render, i tried getting it in normal variable as:
let abc = currentIndexes.map((index) => allCreditorsData?.[index]);
but still couldn't get it. notice the use of optional chaining as well.
then i did sth like:
let def = allCreditorsData?.[0];
here i was able to get the single data row. but only because of optional chaining. if it was not there the data wont appear.

Comment: also, really appreaciate you trying to get me through this. thank you!! if only it solved i would tick the answer as correct. but cant do it without getting the solution.

Comment: let myarr = [];
      let i;
      for (i = 0; i < allCreditorsData.length; i++) {
        myarr.push(allCreditorsData[i]);
      }
      setDisplayCreditorsData(myarr);

This way i was able to get cards displyed with data. but since trimming doesnt happen, all cards gets displayed. and when i have more than 4 cards, its a problem.

tried sth like:
setDisplayCreditorsData(currentIndexes.map((e) => myarr[e]));

But then again the problem that i mentioned above comes back. displaycreditorsdata remains empty.

Comment: @BibekBhattarai It worked, I have updated the solution and also visit codesanbox to test this, please do checkout.

Comment: for some reason it didn't work for me! but I found a solution based around your logic. I will post it as answer so that it has the nice formatting.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Defined states on top so that we can use each of them in any place we want without having to worry about getting not defined error

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [allCreditorsData, setAllCreditorsData] = useState([]);
const [currentIndexes, setCurrentIndexes] = useState([]);
        
// have to define currentIndexes as array state or else we will run into 
//.map is not function or sth kind of error
        
useEffect(() => {
 const allCreditors = () => {
  fetchAllCreditors()
   ?.then((response) => {
    setAllCreditorsData(response?.data);
    setLoading(true);
            
    //setCurrentIndexes is initialized with response?.data?.length because
    //if we do it with allCreditors?.length, it doesnt catch as value,
    //probably the useState render kind of issue
                 
    setCurrentIndexes(
     Array.from(
      { length: Math.min(4, response?.data?.length) },
       (_, i) => i
       )
      );
     })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
   };
 allCreditors();
}, []);
```

and finally we get the chunks from the array we receive into displayCreditorsData, which is then used within return<></> as needed.

```
let displayCreditorsData = currentIndexes.map((e) => allCreditorsData[e]);
const totalCreditors = allCreditorsData.length;

const nextCards = () => {}
const prevCards = () => {}
```

for nextCard and prevCard card function @Anshu solution is perfect.